# Why was my valid edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, tags, moderation, editing

I want to draw attention to other mods regarding rejection of the edit here, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/202550

This post seems directly related to object oriented tag so I have added the proper tag. But two mods have rejected and other approved. I want to know what was the proper explanation for the rejection? Although the rejection have a title as “not even improve a little” how does the statement true for this case?

Answer (score 4):

You have made a number of suggested edits that are trivial in nature.  Adding a tag doesn't qualify as improving the post, especially when the tags you have suggested are fairly broad in nature.

No one is going to start their search by looking at the tag `object-oriented` as a means of refining their question search on the site.

Your edits where you have fixed grammatical issues have been approved, as that does improve the question.

Trivial edits (read: just tags) needlessly bump questions and clutter the main page with questions that have already been answered.  And trivial edits also raise suspicions about motivations - causing people to wonder if someone is attempting to game the reputation system.

In the future, please focus on higher quality edits that improve the grammar or formatting of the post.